# How can I optimize MySQL query for update?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table with 300 000 records. In this table have duplicae rows and I want to update column "flag"

TABLE

```
------------------------------------
|number | flag | ... more column ...|
------------------------------------
|ABCD   |  0   | ...................|
|ABCD   |  0   | ...................|
|ABCD   |  0   | ...................|
|BCDE   |  0   | ...................|
|BCDE   |  0   | ...................|
```

I use this query for updating "flag" column:

```
UPDATE table i 
INNER JOIN (SELECT number FROM table
            GROUP BY number HAVING count(number) > 1 ) i2
ON i.number = i2.number
SET i.flag = '1'
```

This query working very very slowly (more 600 seconds) for this 300 000 records.

How Can I optimize this query?

STRUCTURE OF MY TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inv` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pn` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Part Number',
  `qty` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `qty_old` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `flag_qty` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `vid` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `flag_d` tinyint(1) NOT NULL ,
  `flag_u` tinyint(1) NOT NULL ,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pn` (`pn`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `pn_2` (`pn`),
  KEY `flag_qty` (`flag_qty`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

If "name" is duplicate I want to update flag_qty

Comment: What is the table structure? Is there a primary key available on this table?

Comment: What is the purpose of setting this flag? Are you doing some further processing based on this flag?

Comment: The purpose on this flag is IF have in table duplicate rows this flag is 1. After that I want creating table with duplicate rows and deleting this rows from main table.

Comment: Is the data for all the other columns duplicated as well or do they have different values? I am asking these questions as I suspect there is a better solution for what you are trying to do? Is this a one off de-duping process or a regular occurrence? How do you end up with duplicates? Why is `number` not the primary key (or at least have a unique key) if you do not want it duplicated?

Comment: The data for other columns is different. Numbers is matched, but information in another column ("...more columns...") is not duplicated. For this reason I want to update field flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not already have an index on `number` you should add one -

```
CREATE INDEX table_number ON table (number);
```

**UPDATE** Try this -

```
UPDATE inv t1
INNER JOIN inv t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
    AND t1.id <> t2.id
SET t1.flag_qty = 1;
```

You can create your table with just the duplicates by selecting this data directly into another table instead of doing this flag update first.

```
INSERT INTO duplicate_invs
SELECT DISTINCT inv1.*
FROM inv AS inv1
INNER JOIN inv AS inv2
    ON inv1.name = inv2.name
    AND inv1.id < inv2.id
```

If you can explain the logic for which rows get deleted from `inv` table it may be that the whole process can be done in one step.

Comment: In that case please post the output of `SHOW INDEXES FROM table_name`. I ran your query against 3M rows in a test and it returned in just over 1s on my laptop. Adding the full table structure (output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`) might be helpful.

Comment: I added a sql structure of my table.

Answer (score 1):

Get MySQL to `EXPLAIN` the query to you. Then you will see what indexing would improve things.

Answer (score 1):

`EXPLAIN` will show you **where** it is slow and here're some ideas, **how** to improve perfomance:

- Add indexing
- Use InnoDB foreign keys
- Split query into 2 and process them separately in lagnuage you use.
- write the same idea in MySQL procedure (not sure, whether this would be fast).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a temp table. 1.) select all relevant records into a temp table, set INDEX on id. 2.) update the table using something like this

```
UPDATE table i, tmp_i
SET i.flag = '1'
WHERE i.id = tmp_i.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try (assuming VB.net, but can be implemented with any  language).

```
Dim ids As String =   Cmd.ExectueScalar("select group_concat(number) from (SELECT number FROM table  GROUP BY number HAVING count(number) > 1)")
```

After you get the list of IDs (comma-delimited) than use

```
UPDATE i  
SET i.flag = '1' 
WHERE i.number in ( .... )
```

It can be slow also, but the first - `SELECT`, will not lock up your database and replication, etc. the `UPDATE` will be faster.